# Unable to apply letsencrypt SSL on domain

Tags: ssl, cpanel, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I have installed lets encrypt on WHM but it is not applying on domains. I want when ever I add domain (addon domain) it will be asigned lets-encrypt but it get self-asigned which show website is not secure and not work on HTTPS.

I check in Manage autossl file and remove domain from there and again added to get ssl certificate but it allways get self-signed certificate as i have selected lets-encrypt as autossl.
I also tried to apply ssl from cpanel but when I click on issue it gives error.

"An error occurred the last time AutoSSL ran, on August 22, 2019:"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found solution for my problem. Here is link from where I found solution. [Wildcard ssl certificate](https://medium.com/@utkarsh_verma/how-to-obtain-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-from-lets-encrypt-and-setup-nginx-to-use-wildcard-cfb050c8b33f)
First I had executed these command in CLI of server to install Let's encrypt:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx`

- Create a custom A record, HOST * POINTS TO: Your IP Address(Eg: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx)
- Create a custom A record, HOST @ POINTS TO: Your IP Address(Eg: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx)
- Add a CNAME record, HOST www POINTS TO @ this refers to your IP address.

**Obtaining wildcard ssl certificate from Let’s Encrypt**

`sudo certbot --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d *.example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns-01 certonly`

Replace example.com with you own domain name and **exicute command**.

Deploy a **DNS TXT** record provided by Let’s Encrypt certbot after running the above command
**after DNS TXT** creation follow command line, It will created certificates on sever, **copy or certificate and apply** on you domain.

Comment: It's great that you found a solution! Can you edit your answer to elaborate (even a little bit) about the solution, so that it does not include just a link?

Comment: Every thing that I had done is follow the steps in the link. I have run all those commands (as root user) told in link.

Comment: Still, it's very helpful to at least summarized what you've learned from the link. There had been an extended discussion here, if you'd like more explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Also, if you've answered your own question, please "accept" your answer.